# What is the 'real' monthly cost of a car?

Tags: united-states, car, auto-loan

I'm doing some financing for our future (my wife and I), and we want to purchase a used car - we'll be getting a loan, but along with the monthly payments we'll be making, we want to know what the 'real cost' each month will be for paying for this car - maintenance, gas, sales tax, and monthly insurance premiums (For New York State, Albany County).

How can I find out what these 'additional' costs will be when looking to buy a car?

Comment: Tip: "monthly insurance premium" usually has some annoying fees involved (specifically for car insurance). Strive for semiannual payments if you can afford it.

Comment: This might be different based on your location (at the very least taxes and insurance are likely to be different). Please at least add a country tag.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Excellent point - I've added a country tag AND added my state and county of residence.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> How can I find out what these 'additional' costs will be when looking to buy a car?

If you know what model you're interested in buying you can try out [Edmund's True Cost To Own calculator](https://www.edmunds.com/tco.html). This will estimate the depreciation, taxes and fees, financing costs, fuel costs, insurance premiums, maintenance, repairs, and any tax credits for owning a certain model for various periods of time. You can improve the accuracy be substituting your own calculations, like if you already have an insurance quote.

[Consumer Reports](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/2012/12/what-that-car-really-costs-to-own/index.htm) has a useful chart to demonstrate how much each of those additional costs will add up, percentage-wise. They also list the most and least expensive cars to own.

Comment: Some of these additional costs are one-time payments (like the Sales Tax) or simply the 'value' of the car depreciating (Depreciation, which I assume is what that means) - are these things I can 'write off' if I'm trying to calculate the practical monthly/yearly cost of owning the car?

Comment: Good point. You can [deduct state and local sales taxes](https://www.irs.gov/uac/sales-tax-deduction-for-vehicle-purchases) from your federal tax. However, depreciation of a car is not tax deductible in the same way that depreciation of a television is not tax deductible.

Comment: That's not what I meant - I just mean that I will probably be paying those things only one time, or that they don't equate to what I'll actually be 'paying' over the course of owning that car - so if I'm trying to create a monthly budget, can I ignore those things?

Comment: Just depends on what you're trying to budget for. It sounds like these are things that you'll want to leave out of a budget though